# How to optimize multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql

How do you guys optimize a query that has multiple joins because mine takes so much time?

```
    SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    MEMB.ACCT_N,
    MEMB.LAST_M,
    MEMB.MEMB_N,
    MEMB.MIDI_M,
    MEMB.STRT_D,
    MEMB.LAST_D,
    ACCT_M,
    PrintDate,
    RePrint 
  FROM
    MEMB 
    INNER JOIN ACCT 
      ON MEMB.ACCT_N = ACCT.ACCT_N 
    INNER JOIN Printing 
      ON MEMB.MEMB_N = Printing.MEMB_N
      INNER JOIN RePrinting 
      ON MEMB.MEMB_N = RePrinting.MEMB_N LIMIT 1000) AS MEMB ;
```

And also each table has the same length of MEMB_N of MEMB Table which has 70k data.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

**EDIT**: Added images of my table.

Comment: Could you show us your execute plan?

Comment: What index did you create?

Comment: Hi @D-Shih I tried to create an index a while ago but it took too long so I stopped it

Comment: Can you show the structure for each table ? Also, if you can tell the number of rows in each table, I just want to know the biggest table in the join, so I can suggest to add the index there first and try.

Comment: Please include the table each column belongs to. It's not clear for some columns on the query.

Comment: @Vin You need indexes.  Please read all about indexing at http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: I've updated the question. Sorry bc I'm new in handling this kind of big database and no one mentors me so, I always ask here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [initial] assessment will tell you the indexes you need to create. For example:

```
create index ix1 on acct (acct_n);

create index ix2 on printing (memb_n);

create index ix3 on reprinting (memb_n);
```